# can bluetooth hardware send java commands to android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm researching making some bluetooth hardware for my android phone because I'd like to use my phone hand's free.

What I'd like to do is send a command to my android phone. Specifically, I'd like to programmically change my phone from portrait to landscape mode. The app that will be open at that time is not written by me so I can't change any manifest files.

Similar to the way bluetooth headsets can affect the volume controls regardless of what app is open, I'd like to be able to write bluetooth hardware that can change the orientation of my phone (once connected through bluetooth).

Is this possible?

Comment: as you know you can send data via blue tooth. What you need to do is send commands from device like reset, volume(2) and create an application which can perform this task by receiving these commands. You need to create set of specific commands which can be read by app.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya Is the only solution to write an app that  receives commands? Bluetooth Headsets are plug and play. Can this not be done for my hardware solution?

Comment: you can do it with hardware. You will send sets of commands from your hardware but there should be app on device which will accept command from hardware and perform task on your android mobile. Its like you call your friend on his phone from your phone and till you friend pics call you cannot talk. So data is end between hardware's but to perform task there should be a software which generate actions on android mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to write a service app that acts on Bluetooth intents. (Bluetooth hardware does not need to be modified, as you imply in your question.)

First of all, you should read the Android Bluetooth guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

This guide will explain how Bluetooth works.

The BluetoothDevice class contain a few intents that you might be interested in: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

Comment: Is the only solution to write a service app? Bluetooth Headsets are plug and play. Can this not be done for my hardware solution?

Comment: Headsets (HFP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles)  are handled by the Android OS, as are many other Bluetooth profiles. But there is no built-in functionality for rotating the display a device is connected, thus you must write the code to handle it yourself. If you are looking for a finished solution, you could try apps like "Smart Connect" by Sony.